# How to check the process status after it is killed, or is this even possible?

Tags: java, android, linux, object, process

Some code in which intentionally a null pointer exception is introduced as follows:

[Credits](http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/)

```
// access modifiers omitted for brevity
class MyApplication extends Application {

    String name;

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

//====================================

```
// access modifiers omitted for brevity
class WhatIsYourNameActivity extends Activity {

    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.writing);

        // Just assume that in the real app we would really ask it!
        MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        app.setName("Developer Phil");
        startActivity(new Intent(this, GreetLoudlyActivity.class));

    }

}
```

//======================================================

```
// access modifiers omitted for brevity
class GreetLoudlyActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textview;

    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.reading);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    }

    void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        textview.setText("HELLO " + app.getName().toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

The user starts the app.
In WhatIsYourNameActivity, you ask for the name of the user and you store it in MyApplication.
In GreetLoudlyActivity, you fetch the user’s name from the MyApplication object and display it.
The user leaves the app using the home button.
A few hours later, Android silently kills the app to reclaim some memory.

So far, so good!

But here comes the crashy part…

The user reopens the app.
Android creates a new MyApplication instance and restores GreetLoudlyActivity.
GreetLoudlyActivity fetches the user’s name, which is now null, and crashes with a NullPointerException.

Crash happens because the Application object is brand new, so the name variable is null, leading to a NullPointerException when we call String#toUpperCase() on it.

Command line, when you run this on an emulator or a rooted phone:
Start the app, then:

```
adb shell ps
```

Press home on device and on command line:

```
adb shell ps | grep com.crashy.package
```

and:

```
adb shell kill  <PID from above step>
```

Now, we try to bring back the app from background using recents apps tabs and it crashes as in intended. The question is how can I list the state of all the objects which got killed along with the process - or does killing a process kill all associated objects? Is there a way to fork this process?

Comment: You can store user's name in `WhatIsYourNameActivity` and pass it as an `Intent Bundle` to `GreetLoudlyActivity` and store it there.

Comment: That is not my question. I am intentionally introducing this issue and I want to analyze what exactly happens when a process is killed. What happens to the objects which are strongly referenced?

Comment: Though this isn't an answer, but why do you store name in Application class, why not in shared pref?

Comment: I am creating a test enviornment, to know how the process is killed, what variables are lost and how is the process recreated? Its a purely RnD question and not related to a real life problem.

Comment: A process doesn't exist after it is killed. Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Comment: What about a fork, just before it is scheduled to get killed, say for example in the onPause() method? Actually I am looking for a way to reinstate my new process with the older process data. Not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "...or does killing a process kill all associated objects?"

That's exactly what happens. When a process is killed, all of it's owned memory is reclaimed by the OS - if that didn't happen, there would be a memory leak each time a process died and the OS would eventually run out of memory.

Once a process/app has been terminated, you lose everything that wasn't saved to permanent storage.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is you're trying to simulate persistent storage with a simple variable. For better understanding I would look into the lifecycle of the Android Activity to see how and when the app is "killed" http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Now for a solution I would suggest using the shared preference manager.(your data doesn't look big enough to justify a sqlLite db)

In your storage activity save the name with this

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
Preferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();
edit.putString('name', 'someName');
edit.commit();
```

And retrieve it in your other activity with

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
preferences.getString('name');
```

Comment: That is not my question. What happens when a process is killed? A process is forked? What happens when a process is forked? After the forking process, the address space of the child process is overwritten with the new process data. This is done through an exec call to the system.

Comment: The fork-and-exec mechanism thus switches an old command with a new, while the environment in which the new program is executed remains the same, including configuration of input and output devices, environment variables and priority. This mechanism is used to create all UNIX processes, so it also applies to the Linux operating system. Even the first process, init, with process ID 1, is forked during the boot procedure in the so-called bootstrapping procedure.

Comment: So where is the object?